# How to save a user's input as a variable?

Tags: python, variables, input

I am learning Python and trying to make a program that asks:

1. Where are you from?
   if user responds "Buenos Aires" the program asks
2. Should we kill em all?

That part is done. What I want to do next is make it so that if the user responds to 2 with "yes" the program responds with "Damn straight soldier." Best I can think of is that I should have the user's input from 2 saved as a variable and write something that says if that variable = yes then print("damn straight soldier"). But how do I designate the user input in response to 2 as a variable?

Current code:

```
user_location = input("where are you from?:")
if user_location == "Buenos Aires":
print(input("should we kill em all?:"))
```

Round 2:

```
user_location = input("where are you from?:")
Buenos_Aires = input("should we kill em all?:")
if user_location == "Buenos Aires":
    print(Buenos_Aires)
    if Buenos_Aires == "yes":
        print("damn straight soldier")
```

Round 3:

```
user_location = input("where are you from?:")
if user_location == "Buenos Aires":
    print(Buenos_Aires)

Buenos_Aires = input("should we kill em all?:")
if Buenos_Aires == "yes":
        print("damn straight soldier")
```

Round 4: (still getting "yes" as the end here)

```
user_location = input("where are you from?:")

if user_location == "Buenos Aires":
    kill_em_all = input("should we kill em all?:")

    if kill_em_all == "yes":
        print("Damn Straight Soldier")
```

Round 5 - Copy Paste Code
[image: I copy pasted code RMills says works for his system but is still giving me "yes" as the end.]

Comment: Look at how you've stored the response to the first question within `user_location`... You just need to follow that same approach regarding the next question, assuming they've given the appropriate answer to the first.

Comment: Thanks RMills, I tried specifying a variable 

    user_location = input("where are you from?:")
    Buenos_Aires = input("should we kill em all?:")
    if user_location == "Buenos Aires":
      print(Buenos_Aires)
        if Buenos_Aires == "yes":
            print("damn straight soldier")

but it still just ends at "yes"

Comment: **Please could you update the question with what you've tried?**... It's not easy to read it in the format of the comment box above.

Comment: Will do. Apologies.

Comment: Currently, you're asking whether you should kill them all **before** you've checked what their response to the first question was. You *might* want to try moving your second `input` statement after the first `if` statement. Make sure you're careful with your indentation (as you have been).

Comment: One other thing... You're printing the contents of the `Buenos_Aires` variable... **Did you mean to do that**?... As the response will be shown in the console anyway.

Comment: Looking at round 3... You're asking whether to kill them all **irrespective** of their answer to the first question. **Is that what you intended?** If not... You need to be careful with indentation as this will decide what falls under the scope of that first `if` statement.

Comment: This sound like you are creating a chatbot. It would be useful and easier if you just use the python-aiml (https://github.com/datenhahn/python-aiml-chatbot) such that you can simply change the questions and answer in text file without modifying the code

Comment: You're printing the contents of the Buenos_Aires variable... Did you mean to do that? - The contents in this case is the input field "should we kill em all"? I don't want to print their response. I want to isolate their response ("yes") as a new_variable and have a command "if new_variable == yes print("damn straight soldier"). I don't know how to isolate only their response as a variable though.

Comment: re:chatbot I am just trying to learn tbh.

Comment: @Kardi... The point of the exercise was to learn Python. **Would using that framework really help with that aim? For a beginner?**

Comment: I don't understand how I'm asking to kill em all irrespective of the first answer. Buenos_Aires only gets printed if user_location == "Buenos Aires" no?

Comment: @Steve... But you **have** isolated their response in a variable. Look at how you've stored the location in `user_location`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm proposing is a slight change to your round 3 code.

```
user_location = input("where are you from?:")

if user_location == "Buenos Aires":    
    kill_em_all = input("should we kill em all?:")

    if kill_em_all == "yes":
        print("damn straight soldier")
```

This *looks* to follow your requirements above.

Note that if they don't say they are from Buenos Aires, the program will end.

[image]

Comment: I tried that and still got "yes" as a response. Will add as round 4 in the OP.

Comment: To confirm... Answering `yes` to the second question will print `damn straight soldier` to the console. As far as I'm aware, that is what you were after.

Comment: No that's the problem. It just prints "yes".

Comment: Sorry Steve... That isn't what I'm getting when running that code through my interpreter. If I've misunderstood the requirements, please let me know.

Comment: That's crazy. I copy pasted the code from your comment and I'm still getting an end with "yes". I will see if I can add a screenshot to the OP.

Comment: Yeah I can confirm based on both of our screenshots my code is letter for letter the exact same as yours but giving different results. Maybe an issue with the interpreter? I am using PyCharm community.

Comment: **Are you sure you're running the latest version of your code?** Could it be running an earlier version? I've not used PyCharm so will not be much help there I'm afraid.

Comment: That was it, it was running main! Thanks so much for all your help Rmills I wish I had the reputation to give your answers a thumbs up. I didn't even think to check that.

Comment: Dare I say... Please feel free to accept my answer if you feel it helped. I don't believe there are any reputation requirements for that. And you're welcome!